# Why do I get radically different results when using `aliased`?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from models import SurveyAnswer

Answer = aliased(SurveyAnswer)
answers_1 = SurveyAnswer.query.filter(SurveyAnswer.answer.in_(["A", "B"])).all()
answers_2 = Answer.query.filter(Answer.answer.in_(["A", "B"])).all()
```

`answers_1` gives me the correct results.

`answers_2`, on the other hand, gives me... all `SurveyAnswer`? And it takes quite a long time to run.

Comment: If you define `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` as an environment variable you'll be able to see the actual generated queries in the log. I'm guessing the built-in `query` decorator from Flask-SQLAlchemy misbehaves when you query the alias alone and performs an unexpected join or something similar.

Comment: I would put my money on the class level query-attribute not handling aliases well, meaning that your query is effectively `SurveyAnswer.query.filter(Answer.answer.in_(["A", "B"])).all()`, i.e. a cross join between the table and itself aliased.

Comment: @IljaEverilä If that's the case, isn't that a pretty big bug? That is: Isn't the whole point of aliases to be able to e.g., reference a table by its alias as if it were the table?

Comment: That is the point of `aliased`, but the `query` property is provided by Flask-SQLA, so its implementation may or may not take into account that you call it on an aliased model.